# Boolean value must be kept even after the app is closed

Tags: java, android

I want to know how to keep integer values and boolean values even if the application is closed...

I've tried making it static and pressed back until the application exits (which uses onStop method) but when I closed the application (which uses onDestroy) the variables value goes back to its default value...

I will appreciate to know simple solutions for this one and lastly I want to know if there is a way to edit asset files...

Comment: `I've tried making it static and pressed back` what you're looking for is known as [persistent](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) storage

Answer (score 1):

When you start a program, all variables are stored in the RAM (quick storage). Of course they are gone once you close the app, because all of the apps data in the RAM is being deleted.

If you did not completely close the app, you probably assign a value to your variable in `onCreate()`. Whatever this value is, you should assign it directly where you declare your variable (e.g. `boolean x = true`);

`static` only means that a variable in `class X` is not a property of every instance of `X` (`new X()`), but a unique variable of that class.

What you want to do is save your data in the internal storage. For small amounts of data (up to a few thousand variables), the best way is to use `SharedPreferences`.

They use a key-value system: Each *key*, which is a `String`, is always mapped to a *value*, which can be most *primitive type*s (`boolean`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`) or a `String` / `Set<String>`.

You probably use a (class that `extends`) `AppCompatActivity`. In that, you should already have a method called `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. You will need another one of these so called *life cycle method*s called `onPause()`. This method is being called when your `AppCompatActivity` is **not** focused anymore. This happens for events like

- leaving the app
- closing the app
- turning off the phone
- opening Google Assistent.

This is the code you need to use:

```
public void onPause() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ANY NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("ENTER_THE_NAME", enter_boolean_name);
    // ... you can e.g. use putInt(String, int);
    editor.commit();
}
```

And to get it back:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ANY NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
    enter_boolean_name = prefs.getBoolean("ENTER_THE_NAME");
}
```

---

I don't quite understood what

> edit asset files

means.

You can edit your asset files in any editor and put them into

- `res/drawable` for images
- `res/mipmap` for icons
- `res/raw` for music
- `res/values` for text

And access them using your `Resources` instance (`getResources()`)

If you want to modify graphic assets inside of you app, you can use Androids bitmaps:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
options.inMutable = true;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.whatever, options);
```

You can call `setPixel()` and `getPixel()` on a `Bitmap`. If these options are not enough for you, use a `Canvas`:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

You can draw shapes and other bitmas onto your `Canvas` and it will modify `bitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use shared prefrences or data store .. for that

Answer (score 0):

read [THIS](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) doc, pick your favourite way for storing presistent data, I would use use `SharedPreferences` (walkthrough [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences))

please read some docs and tutorials before asking such basic question... literally thousands answers for such question in Internet, just search

Comment: Do also know how to edit asset files?

Comment: you can't edit anything which is in source of you app